# Can we run custom script for code cleanup using Visualstudio or Resharper?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, code-cleanup

I want to save space while printing source code in visual studio. Is it possible to combine multiple using namespace statements at the beginning of *.cs file to single line using resharper in visualstudio, or using some script that can be run using Resharper code cleanup. I want

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
```

to be formatted as

```
using System;using System.Collections.Generic;using System.Net;
```

Comment: That's horribly unreadable. If you're using .NET6/C#10 or above then use global usings - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-10#global-using-directives

Comment: I understand, but while reading the printout on paper I am more interested in reading other code logic instead of using namespace consuming too many lines on paper.

Comment: Any reason to print out code? Not very environmentally friendly :) You may as well delete the using statements if printed as they wouldn't add anything to rest of the code.